# Not able to Open URL in Python 2.7.10. My Openssl version is 0.98

Tags: python, ssl, openssl, pyopenssl

My scripts are running on server Mac OS Yosemite and they were working fine till last week but now they are throwing **error 54 Connection Reset by peer.**  when checked and debugged , It seems to be an openssl issue.

Python version : 2.7.1

Openssl Version : 0.98

I tried Upgrading the openssl and installed the new version via brew. But python is still pointing to the older version 0.98.

Can anyone please help why I am not able to point python to the newly installed openssl version ?

Comment: Please add piece of python code responsible for opening URL

Comment: @Daweo response = urllib2.urlopen(baseurl + symbolfilepath)

Comment: @Daweo this url is fetching zip file and extracting it in location on mac.